# 'Invalid' selector to be false on initial render TailwindCSS React

Tags: html, reactjs, validation, input, tailwind-css

**Problem:**

I want 'Invalid' selector to be false on initial render that is if the user has just accessed the form or refreshed the page, the :invalid property should not be true. The invalid should only be true if the user can focused on the input once and entered an invalid property.

**Code:**

[This is the code that is being sent to the input so if the user enters value that is length of less than 5 the invalid should be true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ3o7.png)

[If the image is invalid the outline should be red, if focused outline should be blue else if none outline is black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QW8i.png)

[When invalid is true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk9Lz.png)

[When Focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQFTg.png)

[Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OcHR.png)

**Explanation:**

When the user first visits the form, because the value of input is less than 5 the invalid property is true and hence the outline is red. I want the outline to only be red if:

1- User has at least focused once on that input

2- The input value is not valid

3- The user has unfocused from the input.

Condition 2 and 3 are working, but even when user has not even focused once the invalid property is still true

**Expected Output:**

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NVh6.png)

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want, I think you'll need to involve JavaScript. See this page for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#validating_forms_using_javascript